# Jquery remember added input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

**Jquery**

I have these functions where I add and remove input fields. If I update the browser (F5) the added input fields disappear. Is there anyway I could make my website rememeber the added input fields?

I have tried using [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), but couldn't make it work.

```
    var i = 1;
    var max_fields = 10;

    $(".AddInputFields").click(function() {
            if(i < max_fields) {
                    i++;
                    var extrafields = $(".extrafields").append('<ul id="row'+i+'" class="ul_size"><li class="inline-block"><div class="spacebew"><div class="clearfix"> <label class="left">Størrelser fra</label><label class="right"></label></div><input type="text" name="product_size_from[]" value="" /></div></li><li class="inline-block linebew"><p>-</p></li><li class="inline-block"><div class="spacebew"><div class="clearfix"><label class="left">til</label><label class="right"></label></div><input type="text" name="product_size_to[]" value="" /></div></li><li class="inline-block"><div class="clearfix"><label class="left">Antal</label><label class="right"></label></div><input type="text" name="product_amount[]" value="" /></li><li class="inline-block"><button id="'+i+'" name="RemoveInputFields" class="RemoveInputFields">Fjern</button></li></ul>');
                    return false;
            } else {
                    alert("You can only add "+max_fields);
                    return false;
            }
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".RemoveInputFields", function() {
            i--
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
            return false;
    });
```

Comment: Need to see what have you tried with `cookie` plugin..

Comment: You could also use `session/local`Storage considering the browser-support!

Comment: `.append` statement will go in a loop and `var i=0;i<STORED_ADDED_LENGTH;i++`

Comment: You want to update the DOM and save it for forever ? Will you describe what you want ? The state of the page can be saved but only for a particular session ;)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/z8pbaanq/

Comment: This works great @RayonDabre but when I add one and press F5 or hit submit, it adds an additional? Also when I remove one and hit submit, it removes all of them?

Comment: Also, when I try to add 3, it removes one so that I only have 2. Same thing if I add 5, it removes 1 and if I try to add the 5th again, it goes back to 2?

Comment: Do share a fiddle of the same..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6dodxLwq/4/

Answer (score 1):

You could work for example with the localStorage to set your informations in json format.

```
localStorage.setItem("fieldinformationName", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Much better would be a sessionhandling in backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can store information about the input fields the user has added in the local storage using:

```
localStorage.setItem()
```

More information about the local storage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)